# How to change spring's TestRestTemplate Content-Type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I started to have a problem on my spring boot app after adding jackson's library to serialize POJO to XML, `jackson-dataformat-xml`.

When I run the following test it makes a request with the default header of `Content-Type: application/xml` and **I cannot find a way to set this as** `Content-Type: application/json`. It just works if I explicitly put a header with the desired content type in the `.exchange(...)` method.

**This is really weird because it defaults to json if I remove the dependency aforementioned.**

I need to find a a way to configure the bean so I'm not obligated to change all my tests.

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class FooBarControllerIT(
    @Autowired private val restTemplate: TestRestTemplate,
    @Autowired val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
) {

    @Test
    fun testeTeste() {
        val header = HttpHeaders()
        // uncommenting the code bellow makes it work
        //.apply { set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) }

        val response = restTemplate.exchange(
            "/foobar",
            HttpMethod.GET,
            HttpEntity<Any>(header),
            String::class.java
        )

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.statusCode)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

*****EDIT**

I was able to solve it with the following code.

```
@PostConstruct
    fun changeTestRestTemplate() {
        testRestTemplate.restTemplate.messageConverters.removeIf { it is MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter }
        testRestTemplate.restTemplate.messageConverters.add(MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter())
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could remove to overriding message converter of the TestRestTemplate by just adding the JSON-converter. This converter sets the Content-Type-header to "application/json":

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
  restTemplate
      .getRestTemplate()
      .setMessageConverters(Collections.singletonList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()));
}
```